# SharePoint ribbon displays border cant remove

Tags: css

I am trying to display:none on my sharepoint ribbon

## s4-ribbonrow

{
display:none;
}

The ribbon dont get displayed when i do a print preview but the border of the s4-ribbonrow displays why?
I have tried like this

## s4-ribbonrow

{
display:none;
border:none;

}
and also

## s4-ribbonrow

{
display:none;
border-width:0px;
}
it still displays the top border of the ribbon why?

## UPDATE

Still not working
[image]

```
#suiteBar
```

{
border:1px solid red;
border-bottom: 0px !important
}

Answer (score 0):

when you do display none, the element will not be displayed at all, including the border.

I am guessing that there is another element you may be overlooking.

if you are having trouble, it might help to share a screen shot

Comment: Hi i have found out it should be my #suitBar when i set it to be red it display alls red border but when using border:none; my border in the bottom still displays the border i cant remove it i can only change the color of it

Comment: you can try border-bottom: 0px !important

Comment: I have updated..

Comment: you want to remove the border completely? or just in the bottom?

Comment: The bottom only i can remove all border but not the bottom

Comment: its a bit hard to understand what you need. there doesnt seem to be a border in suite bar by default. also, your image doesnt help much :(

Comment: Yes its not but try to be in a sharepoint page an then print preview on the page left click u will se that it will be

Comment: print preview displays a blank page with contents. I am using default theme with your css from the question. perhaps you have a print.css?

Comment: I only have a @media print where i add things i dont wont to display

Comment: Try to add
#s4-ribbonrow{
display:none;

} and u will se it display a border

Comment: nop. still blank. perhaps if you share the exact steps to reproduce, it will help.

Comment: Okej, what should i share?

Comment: site specs: is it default site template, css and contents? full css used and were it is embeded to; steps to reproduce; and full screen shot